# How do I make Google Music's exported music actually useful?

Tags: csv, google-play-music

I've been using Google Play Music as a cloud library for years, not to find new music, but just to stream my existing music acquired and uploaded over the decades. Now the service is shutting down, and after having been conditioned to be able to turn my phone's screen off while listening and to not have ads in between, I'm not going to be able to transfer to YouTube Music as they suggest. I don't want to pay for things I used to take for granted because the whole thing feels like a bait and switch.

They do offer you another option, to download your library in 2 GB chunks, and I've just downloaded and opened the first archive so produced. And, well, it's music salad. It's a cloud of CSV files and MP3s, not grouped by artist, track name, genre, artist, anything; and I'll take their word that the information is all still in there tracked by all these CSV files, but I no longer have any idea what to do if, say, I'd like to listen to one album in consecutive order or find music by one artist.

I have an Android phone and a laptop running Ubuntu.

***What can I do with my*** (from my point of view) ***scrambled library to make it usable again?***

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download a 3rd party music app from the playstore and can sync up your music library in it. It might work! Try using Samsung music app.